# Halt producers until a consumer is free

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, producer-consumer, blockingqueue

Requirement: In a poller / worker scenario, pollers should stop polling remote service until a worker is available to take the task.

Background:
Due to throttling constraints on the number of requests to the remote service, I am trying to segregate polling from the consumers. The constraint here is, that once a task if picked up by a poller, it will timeout if not processed within a certain time. And our consumers can be arbitrarily long running (10s to 10minutes).

Currently looking at the direct solutions, [SynchronousQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html)  seems to be the most simplified approach.

The problem is that if I have 2 pollers and 4 consumers, then while the 4 consumers are processing, the pollers will first pick/poll two tasks from remote, and then wait for consumers to be available. this will cause the 2 tasks to timeout.

Is there a decent workaround this? Or should i be going for lock based mechanism (like: Semaphore) ?

Comment: Why are you trying to decide which consumers you want to push work to?  Just have the consumers *pull* when they're free.

Comment: I am not trying to enforce which consumer gets the work, but rather that once all consumers are occupied, there should not any more polling for new tasks.
I can't have all consumers poll directly, as in a distributed setup this will result in severe throttling. As number of consumers can be quite large (50+ threads) per host. and almost 15-20 hosts. 
Therefore, moving polling to 1-2 poller threads can reduce the overall poll rate from my service.

Comment: Please, add language tag. Currently, only your reference notes about java.